# Trying to run scala (lexer/parser) project from terminal "command not found"

Tags: macos, scala, parsing, terminal, lexer

I'm trying to run my scala lexer/parser program from the terminal but haven't been successful.  Please help.  I'm very new to commands from the terminal.

I have scala installed. I don't know if I have to set the path for it to work or if I simply wrote the command to run it wrong.  I have searched many possibilities but no success. I also checked if there is a problem with sbt, which I think I have also installed.

```
Gladicitas-MacBook:~ david$ cd Desktop
Gladicitas-MacBook:Desktop david$ cd TestIt
Gladicitas-MacBook:TestIt david$ ls
Files       project     src
build.sbt   scala       target
Gladicitas-MacBook:TestIt david$ cd src
Gladicitas-MacBook:src david$ >scala lexer.sc
-bash: lexer.sc: command not found
```

Comment: From your `src` directory try doing: `find . -name *scala*`, what is the result?

Comment: What is the `>` in `>scala lexer.sc`? It's obviously not the part of the prompt (your prompt ends with the dollar sign). Why are you trying to run anything with `scala` in the first place, it's obviously an SBT project, the chances that you'll figure out how to run it manually with `scala` are pretty low.

Comment: Anyway, entering `>scala whatever` reproduces your error: `bash: whatever: command not found`, so just remove the extraneous `>`. Voting to close as trivial typo.